# How to perform a gasless erc20 transfer from the backend?

Tags: openzeppelin, ethers.js

I'm trying to use a relayer to handle my transactions. Initially, I was going for Infura Transactions. Then I saw GSN. And then OpenZeppelin Defender. All of them can help me send gasless transactions and manage them. But, being a relayer, all generate the same problem: sender received by my contract is not the original sender. To solve that, enters EIP712. basically the idea is: send my original transaction as a signed payload to a forwarder contract and from there, my contract will be called appending the original sender. Should be a simple thing! You can get more information here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhAUmULLV44

MY PROBLEM: eth_signTypedData_v4 seems to be implemented only by Metamask. eth-sig-util also works only with Metamask. And **I just can't figure out how to sign my message from my backend server**. There is no Metamask provider in here. Basically, I'm using an ERC20 OpenZepellin contract + https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/metatx

Update: I've also tried etherjs _signTypedData but it doesn't work as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630228/signtypeddata-method-on-ethers-does-not-match-with-erc712-solidity-code/68645218#68645218

Infura doesn't work as well: https://community.infura.io/t/eth-signtypeddata-is-currently-working/2626

Comment: did you find a solution?